# Sync vs Async Request Limits?

Tags: android, ios, asynchronous, parse-platform, cloud

After the huge revamp Parse.com got not so long ago, I'm pretty sure a simple little sentence changed on the now "Pricing Page".

It says:

- 30(Default) Requests per. second

  - 1 Cloud code jobs

.. Now, this is interesting. Before the revamp I'm pretty sure it said Background Jobs instead of Cloud code jobs..

Does this mean that you can now do unlimited async background jobs in iOS/Android? (Ofcourse, with the limit of 30 requests per. second)

Or have I overseen something comletely?

Comment: The ...inBackgroundWithBlock type calls are not background "jobs". Background jobs and cloud code jobs refer to the same thing - code executing independently on the parse server, not directly linked to a client request

Comment: I see... That's interesting..